# awk/tawk to check for duplicates and sort

Tags: awk

I normally use tawk [https://github.com/shawnw/tawk] to sort and remove duplicates and normally I would do this if I want to inspect column 2 of a csv:

```
tawk -csv 'line {![info exsist seen ($F(2))]} {set seen ($F(2)) 1;print}}' inp.csv >out.csv
```

This works fine if I just have to look at the second column of the csv.. but I want to know look at the third column as well.

So, I want to remove duplicates rows where the duplicate string is formed by concat of  column 2 and 3.

Example:

```
1, roman trevor, univerity of oxford,4
2, john williams, cambride university, 5
3, roman trevor, univerity of oxford,40
4, some name, some affiliation, 70
```

Result:

```
1, roman trevor, univerity of oxford,4
2, john williams, cambride university, 5
4, some name, some affiliation, 70
```

I wasnt sure how to adjust the tawk command to account for this.

**Edit:**

Example:

```
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
2|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
3|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology Department of Applied Physics and Materials Science
```

I run:

```
awk -F ' *| *' '!uniq[$2,$3]++' test.csv  >test_out.csv
```

and I get bck:

```
1|Firstname Lastname|California Institute of Technology
```

which seems wrong...

Comment: `tawk` has meant [Thompson's AWK](http://www.tasoft.com/tawk.html) for about 30 years. Someone coming up with a different awk variant and giving it the same name is unfortunate at best.

Comment: In your title you mention sort, can you describe the sorting criteria?

Comment: re: the latest update ... the `|` is being processed by `awk` as an 'OR' of 2 separate delimiters of ' *' and ' '; you need to inform `awk` the `|` is part of the delimiter, eg, `-F ' *[|] *'`

Answer (score 3):

This should work in any awk version:

```bash
awk -F ' *, *' '!uniq[tolower($2),tolower($3)]++' file.csv

1, roman trevor, univerity of oxford,4
2, john williams, cambride university, 5
4, some name, some affiliation, 70
```

Here:

- `-F ' *, *'` sets input field separator as comma surrounded by 0 or more spaces on either side
- `$2,$3` combined column #2 and #3
- `!uniq[$2,$3]++` condition will be true for first instance of `$2,$3` only

Comment: @anubahava: this works like a charm. thank you. I have one follow up qustion: is it possible to extend it to be care insenstive?

Comment: @JohnJ, insensitive means, you want to treat lower abd upper case letters as same correct?

Comment: correct @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @JohnJ, I have also updated my answer now to keep case insensitive thing I MI d, cheers.

Comment: @JohnJ: I have made a small tweak to make it ignore case.

Comment: @anubhava I love this answer - thank you. I have one queston: what do you mean by `condition will be true for first instance of $2,$3 only` ? do you mean that only the first duplicate will be deleted?

Comment: I meant that only the first of the multiple instances of `tolower($2),tolower($3)` will be printed and rest of them will be ignored.

Comment: Just to be clear, if there were 5 duplicates only the first one will be printed - is that correct? is it possible to catch multiple instances?

Comment: Yes that's correct if there are N duplicates only the first one will be printed. We can catch multiple instances but what do you want to do with remaining `N-1` instances? This problem is all about getting uniques only.

Comment: thank you. When I add the `lower` it behaves weirdly.. as in it seems to delete all dupes..

Comment: @anubhava I have made an edit to the original post with the bizzare results I am seeing :(

Comment: Just got back online. When you use `|` as delimiter then `|` needs to be escaped as it is a special regex meta character. So your command would be: `awk -F ' *\\| *' '!uniq[tolower($2),tolower($3)]++' file.csv`

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using `match` function where matching from 1st occurrence of `,` to till next occurrence of `,` and then checking if matched value is NOT present in array named `seen` then print that line.

```
awk 'match($0,/, *[^,]*, *[^,]*/) && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++' Input_file
```

***OR*** to handle case insensitive thing try following code:

```
awk 'match($0,/, *[^,]*, *[^,]*/) && !seen[tolower(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))]++' Input_file
```

***OR*** if you want to keep delimiter as a pipe then try following please.

```
awk 'match($0,/\| *[^|]*\| *[^|]*/) && !seen[tolower(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))]++' Input_file
```

Comment: thank you.. I will try the case insenstive thing: one queestion.. my file I notice now is pipe delimited.. so I guess I change this: `match($0,/,[^,]*/)` to `match($0|/|[^|]*/)` ?

Comment: also, doe this deal with `delimiter surrounded by 0 or more spaces on either side`?

Comment: @JohnJ, please check my edited answers and last one is with pipe delimiter and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

make the `FS` `regex` slightly more complex so the hash array key becomes just 1 new combo column that already amalgamated both `$2` and `$3` instead of manually concatenating the 2 via `SUBSEP`:

> ```
> mawk '!_[$2]--' FS='^[ -?]+|[ -?]+$'
> ```

---

```
1, roman trevor, univerity of oxford,4
2, john williams, cambride university, 5
4, some name, some affiliation, 70
```